# System.loadLibrary with custom library suffix

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

I want to load a dynamic library with native method implementatons, located in `java.library.path`, that has the suffix `.cdl`. The following, unfortunately, does not work.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("java4d.cdl");
}
```

How can I load my `java4d.cdl` library?

Comment: Why not use [`System.load`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use System.load("java4d.cdl")?
Note that the arguments needs to be the absolute path:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976732/system-loadlibrary-with-custom-library-suffix#comment15966233_11976732).

Comment: yeah, we posted at the same time, your comment wasn't visible yet when I started typing

Comment: DOH! Just had to struggle with iterating over the paths, but I got it working. Thanks! :)